# Getting a `Permission denied` error from mount when trying to chroot to Arch Linux

Tags: mount, permissions, chroot

I'm trying to chroot to Arch Linux on my 64-bit Ubuntu box by following the instructions listed [here.](https://www.archlinux.org/download/) Here are the steps I've taken so far:

```
$ curl -sSLo archlinux.tar.gz http://mirrors.abscission.net/archlinux/iso/2016.03.01/archlinux-bootstrap-2016.03.01-x86_64.tar.gz

$ tar -xvzf archlinux.tar.gz

$ cd root.x86_64

$ sudo bin/arch-chroot .
```

For some reason, I'm getting this error when running the script:

```
mount: permission denied
==> ERROR: failed to setup chroot .
Usage: umount -h | -V
       umount -a [-d] [-f] [-r] [-n] [-v] [-t vfstypes] [-O opts]
       umount [-d] [-f] [-r] [-n] [-v] special | node...
```

For reference, here is what I get when I run `cat README` in the chroot:

```
To install Arch Linux from another distribution, a root server rescue system or 
a live system, follow the instructions at
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Install_from_Existing_Linux. A short version
is provided below:

* Make sure your system is running Linux 2.6.32 or later.
* Extract this tarball. If you have enough memory, you can extract it into a 
  tmpfs file system. In the example below, we'll assume that you extracted it in
  /tmp.
* Enter the chroot:
  + If you have bash 4 or later installed, run
    # /tmp/root.x86_64/bin/arch-chroot /tmp/root.x86_64/
  + If you don't have bash 4, run the following commands:
    # cp /etc/resolv.conf /tmp/root.x86_64/etc
    # mount --rbind /proc /tmp/root.x86_64/proc
    # mount --rbind /sys /tmp/root.x86_64/sys
    # mount --rbind /dev /tmp/root.x86_64/dev
    (if /run exists on your system:
      # mount --rbind /run /tmp/root.x86_64/run
    )
    # chroot /tmp/root.x86_64/
* In the chroot
  + Initialize the pacman keyring:
    # pacman-key --init
    # pacman-key --populate archlinux
  + Mount the destination partition under /mnt
* Follow the Arch Linux installation guide
   https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_Guide#Install_the_base_system
  starting at the "Install the base system" step.
```

If it's relevant, I'm running this from within a virtual workspace in [Cloud9](https://ide.c9.io/james_ko/arch-linux). Perhaps it's unable to access the USB device or such? (Please forgive me if I sound like I don't know what I'm talking about, I'm a bit inexperienced with chroots/mounting and that sort of stuff.)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Run `sudo bash -x bin/arch-chroot .` That should tell you where exactly the script is failing.

Comment: As it involves Arch Linux, this question *might* be better asked on [unix.se] where all Linux distributions are welcome. That's just my opinion though, as the problem is likely on the Ubuntu side it should be on-topic here as well.

Comment: Like @ByteCommander said, it is on-topic here. However we don't have much experience with Arch and if the problem turns out to be Arch-related, we'll be of no help. Over at [UNIX.se], they know about Arch and Ubuntu, so you'll probably get much more specific help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem looks like you haven't mounted any partition onto the /mnt, and are trying to pacstrap into the installation media itself. Re-check if you have not missed mounting a partition onto /mnt
    # mount /dev/sdxY /mnt
Then install the base packages, generate fstab, and then chroot to it.